# Trying to update compaction in Cassandra to TimeWindow strategy but it fails with error

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Below is the query I am running to update

> ALTER v2.test WITH compaction = {
> 'class':'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy',
> 'compaction_window_size':'8',
> 'compaction_window_unit':'Days'
> };

Fails with below error:
ConfigurationException: <Error from server: code=2300 [Query invalid because of configuration issue] message="Days is not valid for compaction_window_unit">.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if case sensitivity may be an issue. Did you try: DAYS (all caps)?